# how to create table according to array data and store array data in above databases table

Tags: mysql, arrays, hibernate

```
Array
   {
    "keys": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "hh",
            "hh",
            "jk",
            "ggh",
            "hvh",
            null
        ],
        [
            "dd",
            "gg",
            null,
            "nn",
            "rr",
            "jj"
        ]
    ]
}
```

My array consist like above.I want to create table according to keys values and stored data in above created table. but cannon previously created table. when passing array then created table according to keys values and stored array data into the created table.

** I used hibernate. How I created it.

Comment: Please, show an example of your persistent classes.

Comment: There is no class. I want to create class according to keys values. But key value vill be change. So I want to create table when passing key values.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030665/how-to-add-insert-query-in-spring-mvc-hibernate-project