# How to add insert query in spring mvc + hibernate project

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, sql-insert

My hibernate configuration class include following code

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }
```

My package structures like this

[image]

My daoImpl class like this.

```
@Repository("passArrayDao")
public class PassArrayDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Arr> implements PassArrayDao {


    @Override
    public void passarray(Arr arr) {
  }
}
```

normally we user hibernate for insert update delete data no.

```
@Override
    public Book findBookById(int id) {
        return bookDao.findBookById(id);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return bookDao.getAllBooks();
    }
    @Override
    public List<Book> findBooksByTitle(String title) {
        return bookDao.findBooksByTitle(title);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteBookById(int id) {
        bookDao.deleteBookById(id);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateBook(Book book) {
        bookDao.updateBook(book);
    }
```

bus now i want write insert query into daoImpl class. How I create it.